# How do I prepend a proxy url to all requests on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, http, request, reverse-proxy

I would like to prepend a proxy url to every HTTP request a page makes

I am unable to use Service Workers because they would load **after** the page loads, while I need it to load **before** the page loads.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a `<base>` tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: It wont work with something like this `/style.css` it only works with `style.css` and I cannot modify the pages

Comment: @EliOzcan Use a system proxy? Modify the proxy config of your browser, then you can intercept all HTTP requests.

Comment: The proxy **must** be a browser proxy and not the system proxy as I am making a reverse proxy client and it needs to automatically send all the requests the site makes to the reverse proxy server

Comment: Modify the browser proxy config to your reverse proxy client? Or use a browser extension like *SwitchyOmega* and add a HTTP proxy to the proxy client for the website.

Comment: Can't change that from a script, the proxy server nor the browser will be able to change proxy settings. I have to manually implement it

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you look into burp suite for a robust solution.
Another easier option is the Resource Override browser extension.